# Are there motion light sensors available for multi-gang switches?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, motion-sensor

I suspect this is not available but I have rooms and bathrooms, all of which are multi-gang.  2 plus switches per plate.  Are there slim line automatic switches for these configurations?

Kids are driving me crazy leaving lights on and want to do this but can't find anything but single switch options.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you can't use a single gang device in a multi-gang box?  You'd simply need a new cover plate. Or are you trying to control multiple loads from a single switch?

Answer (score 2):

A 2-gang box simply holds 2 single-gang devices. You need the single-gang device, the hard part will be finding the correct faceplate to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one sensor for each light (looks weird but cheaper than below) -- buy sensors that fit the standard gang wall plate and buy a two-gang wall plate to cover both.

Alternatively, you could move both to a single occupancy sensor using a "dual relay" occupancy sensor. More expensive, but looks better and saves you from messing with wiring between lights.

Not an electrician, so don't know if there is another way to use a single switch for two lights without running 3-wire between them.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this is what you want: 
[2 gang wall plate](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00002NAQT)